# Comparing zeroth Hochschild homology and cohomology for algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and $[A,A]$ its commutator and $Z(A)$ its center.

> Question 1: Do we have $dim(A/[A,A]) \geq dim(Z(A))$?

Note that A/[A,A] is the zeroth Hochschild homology of $A$ and $Z(A)$ the zeroth Hochschild cohomology.

> Question 2: In case $A$ is a Frobenius algebra, do we have equality $dim(A/[A,A]) = dim(Z(A))$ iff $A$ is a symmetric algebra (meaning $A \cong D(A)$ as bidmodules)?

Note that in case $A$ is symmetric we have $dim(A/[A,A]) =dim DHom_{A^e}(A,D(A))=dim Hom_{A^e}(A,A)= dim(Z(A))$ , where $A^e$ is the enveloping algebra of $A$. So one direction is clear, and at least for $A$ weakly symmetric, the computer gives good evidence that the other direction is also true. This would also have very practical use as testing whether an algebra is symmetric takes very long at the moment with qpa while the truth of the above criterion would give a much quicker test.

Question 2 is not true for general algebras. For example we also have $dim(A/[A,A]) = dim(Z(A))$ for the representation-finite blocks of Schur algebras $A$.
(this is a new formulation of a recent question)

Comment: In the repository for [QPA1](https://github.com/gap-packages/qpa) there is, what we believe, a faster implementation of the 'IsSymmetricAlgebra' as of yesterday.  Download the new version, and see if there is any improvement for you in your examples.